# Flutter - TextField: Como cambiar el color de fondo y el hintText

Tags: android, flutter

Estoy empezando en flutter, quiero crear el equivalente al EditText, algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es mi código de la ruta o pantalla, gracias de antemano

```
class SecondRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0x232323),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            TextField(
            ),

          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquí tienes algo similar a lo que buscas:

```dart
Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              border: Border.all(
                color: Colors.green,
                width: 2,
              ),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                Radius.circular(10),
              ),
            ),
            child: TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                  fillColor: Colors.white,
                  hintText: "ID:",
                  hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey)),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: wau, genial, gracias bro!, funciona  como necesitaba

Comment: y para colocar otro Texfield debajo como haria? ando algo perdido con lo de child

Comment: Usa Column , revisa esto :https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/widgets/layout